# Need CSS only for chrome

Tags: html, css

Can you please explain me How can I target css only for Google Chrome?

Thanks
Rakesh Prajapati

Comment: conditional comments are IE stuff

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why would you target Chrome differently from Safari? They use the same rendering engine (WebKit).

Comment: @Chuck, facing 2px line issue in chrome only, rest all browser are fine.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Solution

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    div{top:0;} 
   }
```

JavaScript Solution

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1) {
    // modify anything you want 
}
```

Possible duplicate with:
[How to apply specific CSS rules to Chrome only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only)

Comment: Thanks for solution. it works.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest i dont know if you can specifically target a css for a broswer but Ill toss a quick idea. You could detect the browser with Jquery and set the css programmatically. Jquery has  that ability. for example.

`$("#infot").css("top",$("#header").height()+ offseth + "px"`);

since jquery can detect browsers (webkit/firefox and ie) and chrome is a webkit browser you could do the following

```
if($.browser.webkit){
                adjustSizes();
            }
```

Comment: i use this mainly for ie cause there everything behaves differently and also I can choose not to load several add ons that ie doesn't support

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, Google Chrome, Safari, Opera all of them are [webkit](https://www.webkit.org/) browsers,so it you want to target this browser specifically that would be a real challenge, and as I know there is no media queries hacks of css selector hack available for this, But this piece of Javascript code is really effective,

`var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;`

And it will work on Chrome browser 14 and later, if you want to know more about the Chrome browser hacks,please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496712/1883401).