# How to apply specific CSS rules to Chrome only?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is there a way to apply the following CSS to a specific `div` only in Google Chrome?

```
position:relative;
top:-2px;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a Chrome/Opera specific stylesheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945428/how-to-do-a-chrome-opera-specific-stylesheet)

Comment: What issue are you facing that forces you to do this? Targeting CSS rules for specific browsers is not great design and in most cases, shouldn't be necessary any more nowadays.

Comment: @Pekka this is my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311965/break-between-2-elements-is-leaving-gap-in-chrome , and i found that the only solution is to add those but only for chrome, please help :(

Comment: Did the answer in your original question not help?

Answer (score 207):

**CSS Solution**

from https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/1279/

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, AND NOW ALSO the Edge Browser and Firefox */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  div{top:10;} 
}

/* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    div{top:0;} 
}

/* Chrome 22-28 */
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .selector {-chrome-:only(; 
     property:value;
  );} 
}
```

**JavaScript Solution**

```js
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1) {
// modify button 
}
```

Comment: This rule will apply both safari and chrome

Comment: @AlirezaNoori probably because it applies to both Chrome *and* Safari, not *only* Chrome.

Comment: The CSS solution hack is working for "Chrome only" as `@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { }` - notice the important missing space after the "and". But beware : In CSS preprocessors you'll need to find a way to avoid the correction they make ...

Comment: It's also works in IE Edge, check this https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/1279/

Comment: I used `data-ng-class` for angular and added a `.chrome` class with the JS expression. Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: I found it helped to have the media queries at the bottom.

Comment: The JavaScript check matches in edge as well (In addition to @llamerr's comment that the CSS also matches in Edge)

Comment: The Chome 29+ is testing true for Firefox.

Answer (score 34):

As we know,Chrome is a [Webkit](https://www.webkit.org) browser,Safari is a Webkit browser too,and Also Opera,so it's very hard to target the Google Chrome,using media queries or CSS hacks,but Javascript is really more effective.

Here is the piece of Javascript code that will target Google Chrome 14 and later,

```
  var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
```

and below is a list of Available Browser hacks,for the Google chrome including the influenced browser,by that hack

### WebKit hack:

```
.selector:not(*:root) {}
```

- **Google Chrome**:***All the versions***
- **Safari**:***All the versions***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***
- **Android**:***All the versions***

### Supports Hacks:

```
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {}
```

Google Chrome 28,and Google Chrome > 28, Opera 14 and Opera > 14

- **Google Chrome**:***28 and Later***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***
- **Firefox**: ***64 and Later*** (i.e. this no longer works)

### Property/Value Hacks:

```
.selector { (;property: value;); }
.selector { [;property: value;]; }
```

Google Chrome 28,and Google Chrome < 28, Opera 14 and Opera > 14,and Safari 7 and Less than 7.

- **Google Chrome**:***28 and Before***
- **Safari**:***7 and Before***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***

### JavaScript Hacks:1

```
var isChromium = !!window.chrome;
```

- **Google Chrome**:***All the versions***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***
- **Android**:***4.0.4***

### JavaScript Hacks:2 {Webkit}

```
var isWebkit = 'WebkitAppearance' in document.documentElement.style;
```

- **Google Chrome**:***All the versions***
- **Safari**:***3 and Later***
- **Opera *:14 and Later***

### JavaScript Hacks:3

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
```

- **Google Chrome**:***14 and Later***

### Media Query Hacks:1

```
@media \\0 screen {}
```

- **Google Chrome**:***22 to 28***
- **Safari**:***7 and Later***

### Media Query Hacks:2

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { .selector {} }
```

- **Google Chrome**:***29 and Later***
- **Opera**:***16 and Later***

For more information please visit [this website](http://browserhacks.com/)

Comment: as Sebastian said @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {} affects Safari, tested on v.10

Comment: `@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) { }` is now working for MS Edge.

Comment: @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { .selector {} } now affects Firefox too

Comment: The "supports hack" matches Firefox 64+.

Comment: window.chrome.webstore is undefined in Chrome 100 so the Javascript check doesn't work.

Comment: .selector:not(*:root) {} changes styles on firefox as well as edge

Comment: The initial test for Chrome (later labeled JavaScript Hacks:3) is returning false on Chrome (Canary)

Answer (score 12):

An update for chrome > 29 and Safari > 8 :

Safari now supports the `@supports` feature too. That means those hacks would also be valid for Safari.

I would recommend

@ http://codepen.io/sebilasse/pen/BjMoye

```
/* Chrome only: */
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { 
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: The text is also red in FireFox for me.

Answer (score 10):

[This](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)  css browser selector may help you. Take a look.

> CSS Browser Selector is a very small javascript with just one line
>   which empower CSS selectors. It gives you the ability to write
>   specific CSS code for each operating system and each browser.

Comment: The declaration "css browser selector" is a bit confusing for a simple javascript. CSS itself doesn't support any selections by browsers!

Comment: Sorry but that is what its creator has called it. I have just quoted him :(

Comment: Very lurid phrase of the author ;-)

Comment: ye, don't really want to add a whole load of js just for this :( but otherwise could be helpful.

Comment: The main problem is that it becomes a fragile single point of failure as it is reliant upon a single programmer being dedicated, and that one would need to keep tracking their changes to keep up to date. Basically, a dubious way to deal with an ongoing issue, as while it may help in the short term, it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-create-browser-specific-css-rules-styles.html

Apply specific CSS rules to Chrome only by using `.selector:not(*:root)` with your selectors:

```css
div {
  color: forestgreen;
}
.selector:not(*:root), .div1 {
  color: #dd14d5;
}
```

```html
<div class='div1'>DIV1</div>
<div class='div2'>DIV2</div>
```

Comment: This hack worked for me.  The solutions that relied on screen resolution affected Firefox as well.

Comment: @stevebreese Noticed it to, I suspect it's for modern browsers only.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. But I love the color forestgreen.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer matches Firefox 80+ also.

To target all Webkit browsers (Edge 79+, Chrome, Safari), find a [`-webkit` specific CSS extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions) that is not supported by Firefox (use https://caniuse.com). This is a moving target; one of the Webkit browsers may remove it, and a non-Webkit browser may add support for it.

Here are two examples:

```css
@supports(-webkit-text-security: circle) {
  /* Matches Edge 79 - latest (92) */
  /* Matches Chrome 4 - latest (95) */
  /* Matches Safari 3.1 - latest (15/TP) */
  /* Matches Opera 15 - latest (78) */

  /* does not match Firefox */
}

@supports(-webkit-tap-highlight-color: black) {
  /* Matches Edge 12 - latest (92) */
  /* Matches Chrome 16 - latest (95) */
  /* Matches Opera 15 - latest (78) */

  /* does not match Safari */
  /* does not match Firefox */
}
```

If you actually need Chrome-only, JS is probably the only way to go.

The `.selector:not(*:root) {}` hack in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496712/1218408 still excludes Firefox through version 92 but matches Safari.

Comment: nice, this is the only solution that's worked for me so far (as of Jan 2022)

Answer (score 5):

### How to Apply CSS to Only Chrome

You might try the code below if you want to apply CSS to only Chrome  browsers (Webkit/Blink). Keep in mind there are other browsers that use Chrome's Webkit engine...

```
@supports (not (-moz-appearance:button)) and (contain:paint) and (-webkit-appearance:none) {

  body {
    background: blue;
  }

}
```

In 2022, this code works pretty well and should **work in most Chrome browsers going back to ~ 2013**. It should *filter out* all **Internet Explorer**, early Trident **Edge**, **Firefox**, **Safari**, and many other browsers. But please test!

Keep in mind **Microsoft Edge version 83** and later switched from the old *Trident* engine to Chrome's *Blink* browser engine in May of 2020. So, this should work in the newer Edge browsers, as well. Expect that to function that way as the engines under the covers are close to the same!

**NOTES ON THIS CSS**

As mentioned, the code above works in all browsers that share some modern version of the Chrome Webkit or Blink engines. The two main deciding factors in the code above as far as earliest possible browser support in Chrome-based engines would be support of the CSS feature at-rule `@supports` and the newer Chrome prefixed property `-webkit-appearance:none`. Combined, full support for both in Chrome did not begin till May, of 2013 (I believe). So you can count on Chrome browsers version 28 through today would or should support this CSS hack above. But again, please test!

So let's go through how the hack works.....

Use of the new `@supports` *at-rule* or 'feature check' allows your browser to check if a specific CSS property or feature, and its value, is supported in the user's browser. **The problem is very few older and even newer browsers support the `@supports` CSS trick.** It really did not get support in Chrome till around the May 2013 browser release. So that would be the earliest Chrome browsers supported. **Keep in mind Chrome was not released till 2008, so was a late browser.**

But browser non-support of `@supports` is the main way this CSS is hidden from nearly all other browsers since adoption is still so poor. All browsers prior to 2010 and most prior to 2013 will ignore the rule above. But Chrome version 27 till today would have baseline support of the rule. **Microsoft Internet Explorer 1-11** completely ignore it, and only **Microsoft Edge** version 83 to present (2020-present) would understand the @supports rule. Firefox did not adopt it till 2019 and most Safari user agents starting in 2021. So it is a major filtering tool!

The generic "appearance" CSS property (non-prefixed version) was supported in Mozilla/Firefox as early as 2006 and in Chrome around 2010 in prefixed experimental version with partial support for various features. The Firefox prefix version `-moz-appearance` and the Chrome browser prefixed version `-webkit-appearance` seem to have early adoption so would find support across a wide range of browsers. The value "button" (pre-2006) has earlier adoption in Mozilla/Firefox browsers than "none" for "apperance", so increases the chance you filter out those browsers. "none" for "appearance" in Chrome was a very early supported property value (2010), so was used to widen the range of Chrome browsers possible. So the two prefix rules both remove the most mozilla/Firefox browsers and widen the most Chrome browsers possible in the code above.

So you can probably assume Chrome browsers starting in 2013-present would be able to use the rules below, and seen by all browsers using Webkit engines since then.

The logic `(not (-moz-appearance:none))` hides the CSS block from all Mozilla/Firefox browsers. When combined with limited support for "@support" however, it makes sure even earlier ones are all excluded.

The CSS property `contain:paint` was mainly supported after 2016 in Chrome and Firefox. So this excludes Safari browsers from the CSS block. Some Safari iOS switched to the Webkit Chrome engine, however. So `contain:paint` makes sure those older Safari browsers are excluded from the Chrome Webkit filter.

Lastly, the Chrome prefixed rule, `-webkit-appearance`, applies only to Chrome Webkit browsers. It makes sure the rule below is only seen by Chrome. Keep in mind some later Firefox browsers started to support Chrome prefix properties. But with the extra filters above, they are now hidden from the CSS block above. As mentioned above, `-webkit-appearance:none` has wide enough adoption that it should at least go back to the earliest adoption date of @support at-rules in the web browser. As far as I know that is sometime around May of 2013.

So in summary, the CSS above filters allows only Chrome browsers going back to version 27 in 2013 and Microsoft Edge 83 in 2020 to see the code.

**WHY DO WE EVEN NEED TO APPLY CSS FOR CHROME?**

HTML5 and CSS standards have changed since 2010. There are no more W3C Recommendations where carefully agreed on standards are applied by all browsers. This means browser vendors are *randomly changing their browsers* continually (called **Evergreen**) as far as CSS support. It also means CSS will change on-the-fly, code forks will rarely be aligned, CSS in all the other browsers will rarely match each other, and "hacks" above could change as well.

This failed *Web Standards* movement forms the basis for why new CSS has partial support between browsers and versions, browsers will increasingly not look the same, and these prefixed CSS hacks will be needed in the future. Not good :(

Comment: Safari tested true for this Chrome CSS rule

Answer (score 4):

Have never run across an instance where I had to do a Chrome-only css hack until now.  However, I found this to move content below a slideshow where clear:both; affected nothing in Chrome (but worked fine everywhere else - even IE!).

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari and Chrome, if Chrome rule needed */
    .container {
     margin-top:100px;
    }

    /* Safari 5+ ONLY */
    ::i-block-chrome, .container {
     margin-top:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So simple.  Just add a second class or id to you element at load time that specifies which browser it is.

So basically at the front end, detect browser then set id/class and your css will be befined using those browser specific nametags

Answer (score 2):

If you want, we can add a class to a specific browser.

**Example:**

```js
var BrowserDetect = {
        init: function () {
            this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "Other";
            this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion) || "Unknown";
        },
        searchString: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var dataString = data[i].string;
                this.versionSearchString = data[i].subString;

                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                    return data[i].identity;
                }
            }
        },
        searchVersion: function (dataString) {
            var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
            if (index === -1) {
                return;
            }

            var rv = dataString.indexOf("rv:");
            if (this.versionSearchString === "Trident" && rv !== -1) {
                return parseFloat(dataString.substring(rv + 3));
            } else {
                return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
            }
        },

        dataBrowser: [
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Edge", identity: "MS Edge"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "MSIE", identity: "Explorer"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Trident", identity: "Explorer"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Firefox", identity: "Firefox"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Opera", identity: "Opera"},  
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "OPR", identity: "Opera"},  

            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Chrome", identity: "Chrome"}, 
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Safari", identity: "Safari"}       
        ]
    };

    BrowserDetect.init();


    var bv= BrowserDetect.browser;
    if( bv == "Chrome"){
        $("body").addClass("chrome");
    }
    else if(bv == "MS Edge"){
     $("body").addClass("edge");
    }
    else if(bv == "Explorer"){
     $("body").addClass("ie");
    }
    else if(bv == "Firefox"){
     $("body").addClass("Firefox");
    }


$(".relative").click(function(){
$(".oc").toggle('slide', { direction: 'left', mode: 'show' }, 500);
$(".oc1").css({
   'width' : '100%',
   'margin-left' : '0px',
   });
});
```

```css
.relative {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
}
.relative .child {
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}
.oc {
  background: #ddd none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  float:left;
}
.oc1 {
  background: #ddd none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<div class="relative">
<span class="child">
  ○
</span>
</div>
<div class="oc">
<div class="data"> </div>
</div>
<div class="oc1" style="display: block;">
<div class="data"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We are using JavaScript to detect chrome (and platform) and change style. You can use code bellow:

```js
/* Find existing css selector
selectorName: selector name eg: ".myCssStyle"
*/
function cssFindSelector(selectorName){
    //console.log( "document.styleSheets.length: "+document.styleSheets.length);
    for(var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i+=1){
        var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        for(var j=0; j<sheet.cssRules.length; j+=1){
            var selTxt = sheet.cssRules[j].selectorText;
            //console.log("selTxt:"+selTxt)
            if (selTxt == selectorName){
                return [i,j];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/* change existing css style
selectorName = existing css style to change ".myCssStyle"
newStyleStr = new style eg: "{color:red; border:1px;}"
*/
function cssChangeStyle(selectorName, newStyleStr){
    var idx = cssFindSelector(selectorName)
    if(idx == null){
        return false;
    }
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[idx[0]];
    sheet.deleteRule(idx[1]);
    sheet.insertRule(selectorName+" "+newStyleStr,idx[1]);
    return true;
}


function changeStyleFor_chrome(){
    var txtUserAgent = navigator.userAgent; 
    ////my mobile: 
    //navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
    //my laptop:
    //navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    // iPhone from Mari:
    //navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
    //let n = txtUserAgent.search(/windows/i);
    //let n = txtUserAgent.search(/iPhone/i);
    let n = txtUserAgent.search(/Chrome/i);
    let n2 = txtUserAgent.search(/iPhone/i); 
    if(n >= 0){
        //console.log("agent chrome");
        // here you shall put your style that you want to change for chrome 
        // note that style shall already exists!
        var ret = cssChangeStyle(".myStyleChameleon", "{ color: red!important;}");
        //console.log("ret: "+ret);
        if(n2>0){
          //chrom on iPhone
        }
    }
}


window.onload = changeStyleFor_chrome;
```

```css
.myStyleChameleon {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Change style by JavaScript only for Chrome</h2>
<div class="myStyleChameleon"> This text is GREEN for everything
 except for Google Chrome where it is RED</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also note that Google Chrome on iPhone and Mac display webpage differently (namely we had problem with background-position:fixed). So I would recommend also to detect platform.

Also note that pure CSS hacks are usually targeting both Safari and Chrome and also for different versions different hacks starts and stops working. In other words I think it is impossible to do it reliably only with CSS. Therefore I would recommend do it with JavaScript only.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome provides no own conditionals to set CSS definitions just for it! There shouldn't be a need to do this, cause Chrome interprets websites like defined in w3c standards.

So, you have two meaningful possibilities:

1. Get current browser by javascript ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945428/how-to-do-a-chrome-opera-specific-stylesheet))
2. Get current browser by php/serverside ([look here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php))

Comment: There are definitely reasons why you would want to apply to Chrome but not e.g. Safari or Firefox, e.g. differences in how browsers render <select> elements.  A CSS-only solution would be a lot cleaner than having to involve server- or client-side code.

Comment: Chrome isn't perfect. Just like any other piece of software it has bugs including in the rendering engine, and some are not fixed after a few years. So being able to detect Chrome to counter act the effects of those bugs is important. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?num=100&start=60000

Comment: It's not just CSS which needs to be Chrome-specific. Suppose you want to use Chrome's #:~:text=... feature if available, but, otherwise, you want to use #nearestanchor ?  Too bad we don't have the old IE conditional hacks:  <!--[if lte IE 9]> ...  <![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

I am using a sass mixin for chrome styles, this is for `Chrome 29+` borrowing the solution from Martin Kristiansson above.

```
@mixin chrome-styles {
  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
    and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
      @content;
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
@include chrome-styles {
  .header { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Firefox now reads this rule as well, so it's no longer good if you want to target solely Chrome.

Comment: my exact problem @Mahn, surprised there's no solution in this thread for this...

Answer (score -1):

```
/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
     /*your rules for chrome*/
     #divid{ 
         position:relative;
         top:-2px; 
     }
}
```

check this.it work for me.

Comment: This matches Firefox 63+ and Edge 12+.