# Chrome not being pixel perfect when a is display: block

Tags: css, google-chrome, pixel-perfect

As you can see in [this][1] fiddle, on hover the hover-state of `a` always is one pixel higher than the ul. (You can see this in the fiddle: it even gets over the border of `ul`) This only happens in Chrome (also tested in FF en IE10, but they don't have that problem). Any solution to that?

Note: `overflow: hidden` is not a solution, because I want overflow to be visible for other stuff (sub-menus among others).

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: whiteSmoke;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 150%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
li a {
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 0 white;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em 0.3em;
}
li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: whiteSmoke;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So why can't you just strip out all the superfluous HTML & CSS from your demo?  After you do that, you'll have a concise code example that you can also post into your OP, so that the question remains useful after the fiddle goes dead.

Comment: Does the problem go away when `box-shadow` is removed?

Comment: @Sparky Unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm not seeing your issue in Chrome 11.  Updating Chrome now.

Comment: Only 2011... lol.  Now I am updated to version 24 and still cannot see this issue.

Comment: So, when hovering the hover does not hide the border of the `ul`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your menu is one pixel low in Chrome; there are two browser-specifc approaches that could apply correctional styling only in Chrome. [See Similar Post Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only)

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
  position:relative;top:-1px;
}
```

**JS**

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1) {
  // modify menu styling 
}
```

Comment: And this would effect browsers who don't need the adjustment, too.

Comment: Because it's only a problem in Chrome, I would screw other browsers by doing so.

Comment: @BramVanroy: I thought maybe it's better to have it the other way but ok... Also I posted a link to a guide that said chrome conditional formatting.

Comment: @Sparky: PHP knows what browser you are using so it can propose a conditional... I don't CSS can do that by itself.

Comment: How about just FIX THE CSS problem?

Comment: Don't take it personally, but "fix the CSS" means _write clean CSS that works properly in all browsers_.  Your suggestion is nothing more than a sloppy hack... again, just stating a fact, not a personal attack.  Once the OP cleans up his example, others can suggest more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Sparky: I wouldn't take it personally if everyone acts in a respectable and professional manner. But how else is he suppose to use browser conditional CSS code if CSS does not know what browser he is working in. Maybe CSS can somehow figure out what browser you are in but if it can't you have to use either Javascript or PHP so I posted a proper PHP solution.

Comment: Devin, he's not specifically asking how to make browser conditional CSS (absolute last resort).  He's wanting to know why this is happening and how to fix his CSS.  In other words, I am not suggesting that CSS should have the ability to figure out your browser... I am suggesting that one writes CSS that works in all browsers.

Comment: @Sparky: Alright that makes sense, unfortunately I am not that knowledgeable in CSS to know which properties only apply to which browsers. Hopefully someone with more CSS skills can propose a CSS only answer but if not I hope mine will suffice and is able to fix the bug Bram is having.

Comment: Devon, thanks for your effort. As Sparky said, this will only be a last resort solution!

Comment: @BramVanroy: That is understandable, hopefully someone will come along in the next few days and give you an only CSS solution. But if not at least you have something to work with. Have a good day, and I wish you the best of luck on your project.

Comment: Actually, I used the JS solution from the link you gave. Thanks!