# How to over-ride img-width from bootstrap? Set css rule to null?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I'm using bootstrap and I have a very small custom over-ride style sheet that loads last and it seems to work great, However I found that Bootstrap has

```
img {img-width:100%;}
```

I found it is causing Chrome to really downsize some images, which show fine in FF so I tried using the inspector and if I eliminate the rule, all seems fine.. but I can't figure out how to do that in a sub css sheet, since

```
{img-width: ;}
```

is not legal? and I tried

```
{img-width:100;}
```

which seemed to make the inspector happy since it knew that it was junk but did not work in real -life, since it ignored the rule?? So how do you set a css property to null in a sub style sheet?

Comment: img-width is not a valid property , it has to be max-width

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply specific CSS rules to Chrome only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only)

Comment: img {img-width: 100%} is what the Chrome inspector shows as coming from Bootstrap (and as valid)someone suggested img {img-width: auto} and this gets marked as invalid in the chrome inspector (which achieves the desired result in the inspector) but I guess because it is invalid it does not get applied from css as an over-ride..

Comment: This is not a dupe, nothing really chrome specific here, I am trying to override using a CSS style sheet listed after the bootstrap style which is applied , However I found that Bootstrap has img {img-width:100%;} is recognized as valid and applied as I can see in the Chrome dev inspector. Someone suggested ,  img {img-width:auto;} which the Chrome inspector shows as invalid, but it achieves the result in the inspector but does not override from css presumably because it it is invalid..

Comment: Known issue in Bootstrap https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer!! img {img-width : none;}
Thanks to an answer from Github on the bootstrap issues...
Would appreciate  Madth3 and Roman C correcting...