# browser compatibility Issue for chrome

Tags: html, css

I want to set margin and padding for only chrome browser.

how can i set css for only chrome browser because there are some more padding  or margin for that

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following link-- it may surely help you-

[How to apply specific CSS rules to Chrome only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only)

Also you can detect browser with the help of following script --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome')!=-1){
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_script.css"/>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks
how can i apply for all the browser if i add the above class and comment out for other then it will work only for chrome other it will not work

Comment: @user2833721 --- could you be specific in your details. what actually do you want? i didn't get anything from your comment.

Comment: can you please check this site
eheuristic.com/newehs
check in both browser
the right side Android Application AND Open Source Customization will shown right thing in FF but not in chrome

Comment: @user2833721--- sry dear !! but i didn't found any difference on the page in both the browser-- Firefox and Chrome. Result was exactly same in both the browser.

Comment: Ok
Thanks a lot

Actually  I use Linux so i have problem
I check in windows 
it will work perfect in that

Comment: @user2833721 --- Although it is a bit odd, but can i ask a favor from ur side--- if u think that this answer is useful to you then can u mark this answer as accepted answer. because i need some reputation point. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

try detecting browser using

```
navigator.userAgent
```

for further assistance [browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

once detected in javascript or jquery add the class with margin and padding to the body