# Use different style(Only one) for Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: html, css

I have this style inside a PHP file that is applied to an Element

```
line-height: 120px;
display: list-item;
display: -moz-inline;
list-style: none;
```

I want that if browser is Chrome then `display:list-item` and if it is Mozilla then `display: inline`

The above style works well in Chrome, but in Mozilla it is applied as `display: list-item`

Comment: What you want to do? It´s way to the hell... Do you have problem in any browsers with any value?

Comment: Actually the above style is for `a` tag and on top of `a` there are images. I need to align those images vertically in middle

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/ maybe this could help....

Comment: @Umair There is no display `-moz-inline` property, the valid properties are `-moz-inline-box`, `-moz-inline-stack` and `-moz-inline-grid`.

Comment: @Umair: Can you show us your HTML and show how t should looks? Using styles for different browsers can work now, not in the future.

Comment: @Umair like that demo? - http://jsfiddle.net/038n6kL7/

Answer (score 0):

[How to apply specific CSS rules to Chrome only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only)

Here's a bunch of methods, that actually can help you. Just set style for mozilla and then overwrite it by the Chrome hack. But abstracting from that solution: maybe show us some bigger part of code (or even jsfiddle) so we can help you style it properly without any hacks.