# CSS @supports (::pseudo-element)

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I want to change an area to max overflow:scroll only if `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` is supported.

Is that possible somehow in pure CSS? As it seems `@supports`only checks rules, no selectors.

Comment: I think you will need https://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 11):

You can now use [`@supports selector()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-4/#at-supports-ext) to target pseudoelements. Here is a relevant example for your use case:

```
@supports selector(::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb) {

    .scroll-container {
        overflow: scroll
    }

}
```

Please see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/42xdu3po/), which demonstrates browser support for `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` in

1. Chrome 86
2. Edge 87
3. Opera 72

*but not*

1. Firefox 82
2. Safari 12

---

**As of February 2024, [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_supports_selector) for `@supports selector` is roughly 94%.**

Comment: There are many (mostly outdated) suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496712/2083613), but as of 2021-09, `@supports selector(::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb){/*Chrome yay, Firefox nay*/}` does work if it must.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. `@supports` only deals with property-value combinations. The only way you could do this in pure CSS is with a CSS hack targeting browsers that support `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`. (Not enough browsers support `@supports` for it to be useful in checking support for `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` anyway.)

Comment: Outdated now, see most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up to the previous answer, you can just write the pseudo selector, if a browser doesnt support the prop, it will skip the css declaration.

For example:

`li::marker{color:blue}`

won't be seen by older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to identify Webkit browsers. It's the most specific pseudo selector I could find that no other engine seems to have (yet):

```
CSS.supports(`selector(input[type='time']::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator)`)
```