# Is it possible to prevent moving the cursor to the start of an input field when type changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, forms

I'm currently creating a Password field with an option to hide or display the password in React/Ionic.

- I want to **keep focus on the password field** when you change the type of the input. (like [PayPay Login page](https://www.paypal.com/signin) does) I'm doing it with `event.preventDefault()` on `mousedown`-Event.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')

function toggleVisibility() {
  if (input.type === "text")
    input.type = "password"
  else
    input.type = "text"
}

function keepFocus(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Password" type="text">
<button onmousedown="keepFocus(event)" onclick="toggleVisibility()">Show Password</button>
```

**Problem**

- When I **change the type of the input field** the cursor **flips back to the start** of the input field. I would like to keep the cursor where it was before. (Again like on [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/signin))

Answer (score 3):

If you were to look at PayPal's own code which you linked to, you'd see it's just a matter of calling `input.focus()` in a single event-listener:

> ```
>       function hidePassword(e) {
>           if (baseType === 'tel') {
>               $(field).addClass('tel-password');
>           } else {
>               field.setAttribute('type', 'password');
>           }
>           $(btnShow).removeClass('hide');
>           $(btnHide).addClass('hide');
>           field.focus();
>           e.stopPropagation();
>
>           login.logger.log({
>               evt: 'is_pwd_sh',
>               data: 'N',
>               instrument: true
>           });
>           login.logger.pushLogs();
>       }
> ```

Which can be simplified down to my example below, with some alterations:

- The default `type=""` should always be `password`. Users *expect* password inputs to not suddenly show the password-they're-typing-in to everyone who can see their screens (especially when screen-sharing or projecting to a TV or giving a presentation, etc).
- I've changed the `querySelector` call to embedding the target `<input type="password" />` in `<button data-for="" />` to avoid problems caused by running `querySelector` or `getElementById` before the `DOMContentLoaded` event, as is often the case with JS snippets people post around the Internet.
- The calls to `event.stopPropagation()` (in PayPal's code) or `event.preventDefault()` (in your code) are superfluous and unnecessary. The important thing is calling `input.focus()` in the same event-handler that changes the `HTMLInputElement.type` property.
- Avoid using `onmousedown` with buttons. The `'click'` event works for all kinds of interactions (mouse, keyboard, touch, etc) while the `'mousedown'` and `'mouseclick'` events are only raised by *actual* mouse input (though often touch too).

  - Despite the event's name being `'click'` and [it being formally defined as a `PointerEvent`](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#click), it isn't the same thing as `'mouseclick'`, so you should imagine the name coming from the on-screen button "clicking", *not* the sound of a physical mouse button clicking. [The `<button>`'s `'click'` event will be raised by the user pressing their spacebar](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow-activation), for example.

```js
function toggleVisibilityOnClick( event ) {
    
    const button = event.currentTarget;
    const input = document.getElementById( button.dataset['for'] );
    if( !input ) throw new Error( "Couldn't find password input." );
    
    if( input.type === 'text' ) {
        input.type = 'password';
    }
    else {
        input.type = 'text';
    }

    input.focus();
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Password" type="password" id="pwdInp" />
<button data-for="pwdInp" onclick="toggleVisibilityOnClick(event)">Show Password</button>
```

---

[Microsoft's browsers have `-ms-reveal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/password-reveal), which makes your toggle redundant, so you should hide the toggle in that case:

```
@supports selector(::-ms-reveal) {
    
    input[type="password"] + button[data-for] {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports
- [CSS @supports (::pseudo-element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000865/css-supports-pseudo-element)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Microsoft_Extensions

Comment: Thanks for your detailed. Answer! Do you know a solution where you use the `onMouseDown preventDefault`-option which does not effect the cursor position?

Comment: @Hey You shouldn't be using `onmousedown` for this (as it's less accessible than `onclick'), so why are you asking?

Comment: @Hey I've updated my answer, it turns out `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` are entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the update. I would like to use it in my react app and useRef with forwardRef makes the code a lot more "complex". A solution just with an event is much simpler. (So I think it's personal preference :) )

Comment: @Hey If you're using React then you should not be touching the DOM directly at all, so my code won't help you there.

Comment: That's the reason. :)