# Define Chrome IE Tab Specific Style Sheets

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

I need to define specific style-sheets, only for chrome IE Tabs. Is there a way around?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to make specific css styles in different browsers. You could check my simple sample below:

```css
/* IE10+ specific styles go here */

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  div {
    background-color: aqua;
  }
}


/* Chrome 29+ specific styles go here */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
  div {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px; height:200px"></div>
```

The `div` will have different colors in IE and Chrome. For more detailed information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417056/how-to-target-only-ie-any-version-within-a-stylesheet) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only).