# How can I apply CSS to Chrome browser and not Mozilla?

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, styling

I'm trying to style a checkbox specifically for the chrome browser, and I've tried media queries like `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)`, but Mozilla seems to have updated their browser because webkit styling now works.

Does anyone have an updated media query or is my only solution to hide the original checkbox and design a new one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only
This will answer your question!

Comment: I know it was only ever intended as a temporary fix and I never used it all that much, but *vendor-prefixing* from the early 2010s is shockingly broken now, isn't it?