# How to change CSS style class attributes depending on Browser and Platform

Tags: css

How do I change reliably CSS style class attributes (properties and values) based on browser and platform?

Note I would like to really change CSS style class attributes, many examples is adding new style class to element(s). But in my case I have multiple elements with particular style (let's call the style .browser_chameleon_style) and I want to change style's attributes, and not list all elements and adding to them new style classes.

Note I read some [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496712/1093607) about CSS hacks like `.selector:not(*:root) {}` but it usually targets both Chrome and Safari and is not reliable for different versions. I want something more reliable.

Comment: Browser detection can be very unreliable. Can you describe the particular problem you are trying to overcome?

Comment: Originally I had trouble with background-position:fixed on IPhone. I used platform detection and changed to 'scroll'. But this is general question and I have quite working solution which seems quite realiable. But yes some browsers are using simillar navigator.userAgent strings so one must be careful, but not same and they can be distinguished. Anyway I want to keep it as general question not for particular issue. Because browsers are behaving differently and this is universal way how to detect them and write specific style for them to page looks simillar or at least not terrible...

Answer (score 0):

We are using JavaScript `navigator.userAgent` to detect Browser and Platform. Then we use JavaScript to change CSS style attributes.

```
document.styleSheets[i].deleteRule(j);
document.styleSheets[i].insertRule(".mySelector {color:red;},j);
```

You can use working code bellow:

```js
/* Find existing css selector
selectorName: selector name eg: ".myCssStyle"
*/
function cssFindSelector(selectorName){
    //console.log( "document.styleSheets.length: "+document.styleSheets.length);
    for(var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i+=1){
        var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        for(var j=0; j<sheet.cssRules.length; j+=1){
            var selTxt = sheet.cssRules[j].selectorText;
            //console.log("selTxt:"+selTxt)
            if (selTxt == selectorName){
                return [i,j];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/* change existing css style
selectorName = existing css style to change ".myCssStyle"
newStyleStr = new style eg: "{color:red; border:1px;}"
*/
function cssChangeStyle(selectorName, newStyleStr){
    var idx = cssFindSelector(selectorName)
    if(idx == null){
        return false;
    }
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[idx[0]];
    sheet.deleteRule(idx[1]);
    sheet.insertRule(selectorName+" "+newStyleStr,idx[1]);
    return true;
}


function changeStyleFor_chrome(){
    var txtUserAgent = navigator.userAgent; 
    //my mobile: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
    //PC Chrome: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    //PC Opera : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/102.0.0.0
    //iPhone   : Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
    let chromeTxtIdx = txtUserAgent.search(/Chrome/i);
    let operaTxtIdx = txtUserAgent.search(/OPR\//i);
    //let platformTxtIdx = txtUserAgent.search(/iPhone/i); 
    let platformTxtIdx = txtUserAgent.search(/android/i); 
    if(chromeTxtIdx >= 0 && operaTxtIdx == -1){
        //console.log("browser Chrome");
        if(platformTxtIdx >= 0){
            //console.log("browser Chrome platform Android");
            // here you shall put your style that you want to change for chrome on Android
            // note that style shall already exists!
            var ret = cssChangeStyle(".browser_chameleon_style", "{ color: red!important;}");
        }else{
            //console.log("browser Chrome platform not Android");
            var ret = cssChangeStyle(".browser_chameleon_style", "{ color: orange!important;}");
        }
    }
}

window.onload = changeStyleFor_chrome;
```

```css
 .browser_chameleon_style {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h2>Change style by JavaScript based on Browser and Platform</h2>
  <div class="browser_chameleon_style"> This text is 
  <br>RED.....for Chrome on Android
  <br>ORANGE..for Chrome on other platforms
  <br>GREEN...for other browsers
  </div><br>
  <div class="browser_chameleon_style">And it is done for all elements at once</div>
  <div class="browser_chameleon_style">Even when there is many of those elements</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Platform detection is for example useful cos Google Chrome and Safari on iPhone does not display properly `background-position:fixed` so if we detect iPhone we change style to `background-position:scroll`.